# Forcing Spring Boot 2 to use JDK Proxy failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

`spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false` in
`application.properties` file doesn't help me to force Spring Boot2 to use JDK Proxy.

**Aspect**

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    
private final String POINT_CUT = "execution(* weatherReport.entity.*.*(..)))";
@Pointcut(POINT_CUT)
private void pointcut() {}
@Before(value="pointcut()")
public void before(JoinPoint pjp) {
    logger.info(" Check for user access ");
    logger.info(" Allowed execution for {}", pjp);
}
```

Target Component:

```
@Component
public class Hello {
    public String name = "default";
    public  String helloStr = "Guys";
    public void saySomething() {
        System.out.println(this.name+":"+this.helloStr);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private WeatherQueryService weatherservice;
@Autowired
private Hello hello;
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
public String sayHello() {
        System.out.println(weatherservice);
        System.out.println(hello.getClass());
        hello.saySomething();
        System.out.println(hello.getClass());
        System.out.println(weatherservice.getClass());
        return "hello world";
}
```

> result: class
>   weatherReport.entity.Hello$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b853a6c3

**application.properties**

```
spring.aop.auto=true
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I missed some important theory about JDK Proxy, the target class should implement interface then we can use JDK Proxy.
In my code, weatherservice implements an interface, and when I set  spring.aop.proxy-target-class to be false, Spring Boot 2 uses JDK Proxy:

class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62

but when I set spring.aop.proxy-target-class to be true, Spring Boot2 uses default cglib Proxy:
class weatherReport.service.impl.WeatherQueryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$40d58c6